# Let $a$ and $b$ two real numbers such that $0<a,b<0/5$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $a$ and $b$ two real numbers such that $0<a,b<0/5$. I want to prove that $0<a+b-2ab<0/5$. Please help.

Comment: By $0/5$ you mean $1/2$, right?

Answer (score 5):

Hints: $a+b-2ab=a+b(1-2a)$. Then using the facts that $0<a,b<0.5$

Comment: Jlamprong Please explain

Comment: the left inequality is obvious, isn't it?
the right one, you only need to use $b<0.5$. I am sure from this point you should be able to finish it

Comment: Jlamprong Thanks